# How can I refactor my RESTless routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've finished building a toy app to better learn Rails but I'm unsatisfied with my current implementation of the routes. I'd like to DRY them up but I'm not sure how to go about it since the Rails docs cover only REST routes with resources. Here's my `routes.rb`:

```
  root 'index#home'

  # Avatars
  get '/:user/change_avatar' => 'avatars#edit', as: :change_avatar
  post '/:user/change_avatar' => 'avatars#update', as: :update_avatar

  # Users
  get '/:user' => 'users#show', as: :show_user
  get '/:user/edit' => 'users#edit', as: :edit_user
  delete '/:user' => 'users#destroy', as: :destroy_user

  # Playlists
  post '/:user/playlists' => 'playlists#create', as: :playlists
  get '/:user/:playlist' => 'playlists#show', as: :show_playlist
  get '/:user/:playlist/edit' => 'playlists#edit', as: :edit_playlist
  patch '/:user/:playlist' => 'playlists#update', as: :update_playlist
  delete '/:user/:playlist' => 'playlists#destroy', as: :destroy_playlist

  # Tracks
  post '/:user/:playlist/tracks' => 'tracks#create', as: :tracks
  get '/:user/:playlist/:track' => 'tracks#show', as: :show_track
  get '/:user/:playlist/:track/edit' => 'tracks#edit', as: :edit_track
  patch '/:user/:playlist/:track' => 'tracks#update', as: :update_track
  delete '/:user/:playlist/:track' => 'tracks#destroy', as: :destroy_track

  # Photos
  delete '/:user/:playlist/:track/photos/:id' => 'photos#destroy', as: :destroy_photo
```

As can be noticed, the `:user`, `:playlist`, and `:track` dynamic segments appear in almost all the routes. How can I improve upon this?

Comment: Using scopes can be helpful

Comment: Take a look https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/building-a-restful-api-in-a-rails-application

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Very helpful. You can have a look at my answer below to see what I ended up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kiloreux's suggestion to use scopes, here's what I ended up with -- exactly what I was looking for:

```
  root 'index#home'

  scope '/:user' do
    get '/change_avatar' => 'avatars#edit', as: :change_avatar
    post '/change_avatar' => 'avatars#update', as: :update_avatar
    get '/edit' => 'users#edit', as: :edit_user
    delete '/' => 'users#destroy', as: :destroy_user
    post '/playlists' => 'playlists#create', as: :playlists
  end

  scope '/:user/:playlist' do
    get '/' => 'playlists#show', as: :show_playlist
    get '/edit' => 'playlists#edit', as: :edit_playlist
    patch '/' => 'playlists#update', as: :update_playlist
    delete '/' => 'playlists#destroy', as: :destroy_playlist
    post '/tracks' => 'tracks#create', as: :tracks
  end

  scope '/:user/:playlist/:track' do
    get '/' => 'tracks#show', as: :show_track
    get '/edit' => 'tracks#edit', as: :edit_track
    patch '/' => 'tracks#update', as: :update_track
    delete '/' => 'tracks#destroy', as: :destroy_track
    delete '/photos/:id' => 'photos#destroy', as: :destroy_photo
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `Playlist` routes, you can do something like this:

```
resources :playlists, except: [:index, :new]
```

That will create all the normal routes except the `index` and `new` routes. For the `Avatar` routes, you can try this:

```
resources :avatars, only: [] do
  get :edit, on: :member, as: :change_avatar
  post :update, on: :member, as: :update_avatar
end
```

Try reading [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) for more on Rails routing.

Comment: damn ...I was going to suggest using `resources` but you beat me too it.

Comment: Not quite. You've given a REST solution while my routes are RESTless so your suggestion is misleading. Apparently the right approach in this case is to employ scoped routes. See my answer below for how I did it.